# Grab numbers from file and add together

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a file like this
file A :

```
min:353 max:685 avg:519
min:565 max:7984 avg:4274
min:278 max:5617 avg:2947
min:624 max:6768 avg:3639
min:27 max:809 avg:418
min:809 max:3685 avg:2247
min:958 max:2276 avg:1617
```

I trying to get last two line of avg numbers to ad them together.
Like `2247+1617` than output the value `3864`.
How can I achieve it?

So far my code is like this : (sorry for limited knowledge)

```
tail -n 2 file.A | awk -F '[: ]' '{print $6}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to add the last field.  This would add the last field to a variable.  The `END` block is executed after the input is exhausted, so `sum` would be printed at the end:

```
tail -2 file.A | awk -F: '{sum+=$NF}END{print sum}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an `awk` only

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR {n=NR;next} FNR>n-2 {sum+=$NF}END{print sum}' file.A{,}
3864
```

Or you can just sum the two last value:

```
awk -F: '{f=s;s=$NF}END{print s+f}' file.A
3864
```

Comment: The second approach reads the file once, which works better with pipelines, and works better with massive files too.  That said, if the data is in a massive file, `tail` can seek to the end without having to read the whole file, which `awk` can't do readily, so the solutions preprocessing with `tail` have their merits when the data is in a file and the file is really big.

Answer (score 3):

Similar approach as [devnull's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23465352/970195) answer but using `tac`.

```
tac file.A | awk -F: '{sum+=$NF}NR==2{print sum;exit}'
3864
```

- `tac` reverses the file
- Using `awk` we `sum` the last column (`$NF`).
- When line number is 2 we print the `sum` and exit.

Comment: @Jotne `tac` and `tail` solutions will have better performance if the file is huge.

Comment: `tac` -- a little known, under-utilized utility.

Comment: `tac` is the reverse of `cat`, easy to remember.